# Evaluating a convolutional neural network on an imbalanced (academic) dataset

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, classification, imbalanced-datasets, pose-estimation

I have trained a posture analysis network to classify in a video of humans recorded in public places if there is a) shake-hand between two humans, b) Standing close together that their hands touch each other but not shake hand and c) No interaction at all.
There are multiple labels to identify different parts of a human. The labels are done to train the network to spot hand-shaking in a large dataset of videos of humans recorded in public.
As you can guess, this leads to an imbalanced dataset.
To train, I sampled data such that 60% of my input contained handshaking images and the rest contained different images than hand-shaking.In this network, we are not looking at just labels but also the relative position of individual labels wrt to one another. We have an algorithm that can then classify them into the three classes.

I am stuck on how to evaluate the performance of this network. I have a large dataset and it is not labeled. So I have decided to pick 25 from class A) and B) and 50 from class (C) to create a small dataset to show the performance of the network.
And to run the network on the large dataset without labels, but because classes A and B are quite rare events, I would be able to individually access the accuracy of the network prediction of True positive and false-positive cases.

Is this a sound way to evaluate ? Can anyone having experience or opinion share their input on this? How else can I evaluate this?

Comment: Can you please help me understand what the final labels are for your optimization problem? Are they 3 labels 1) shake hands, 2) standing close, 3) no interaction; or are they human body keypoints such as in COCO. If the labels are a combination such as in a multitask setting, please share that as well.

Comment: They are not three labels, but by thresholding a set of labels and by assumptions from data we categorize each video into one of these classes. All the three classes are made of the same set of labels, it's just their combinations and likelihood values that decides which of the three classes they fall into.